# explain why the location of a variable's declaration disables me from changing its value

Tags: c, variables, declaration

I have a variable that behaves differently depending on where I declare within the same function. I would like to understand what is happening.

**In this function I have included the variable declaration and initialization in the both places that produce a different outcome solely to illustrate what is happening. When I run the program, i am not declaring the variable twice, only once, in either place.**

I refer to variable temp, I have commented the SCENARIO 1 AND SCENARIO 2

the C function

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        // ensure proper usage
        if (argc != 4) // we need four arguments
        {
            printf("Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // remember filenames
        char* infile = argv[2];
        char* outfile = argv[3];

        // the factor
        int n = argv[1][0] - '0';

        // SCENARIO 1) HERE HERE HERE HERE THIS IS THE VARIABLE I AM DISCUSSING!!!!!!!
->      int temp = n; // WHEN DECLARED HERE AND INITIALIZED AT TIME OF CREATION
                      // gdb displays its value equal to the value of n


        // open input file 
        FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
        if (inptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
            return 2;
        }

        // open output file
        FILE* outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
        if (outptr == NULL)
        {
            fclose(inptr);
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
            return 3;
        }

        // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
        fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

        // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
        fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

        // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
        if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
            bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
        {
            fclose(outptr);
            fclose(inptr);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
            return 4;
        }

        //gdb break to check the previous values


        // SCENARIO 2) HERE HERE HERE HERE THIS IS THE VARIABLE I AM DISCUSSING!!!!!!!!
->      int temp = n; // WHEN DECLARED HERE AND INITIALIZED THE VARIABLE HERE
                      // gdb displays its value equal to 0 and not n

        // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
        fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

        // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
        fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

        // determine padding for scanlines
        int padding =  (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

        //gdb break to check the new values

        // iterate over infile's scanlines
        for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
        {
            // iterate over pixels in scanline
            for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
            {
                // temporary storage
                RGBTRIPLE triple;

                // read RGB triple from infile
                fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }

            // skip over padding, if any
            fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

            // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
            for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }

        // close infile
        fclose(inptr);

        // close outfile
        fclose(outptr);

        // that's all folks
        return 0;
    }
```

why do I get a different value when the n nor temp is changed in any way by the code?

Comment: Do you declare the variable 2 times?

Comment: @llmo Euro As I mentioned in my question "When I run the program, i am not declaring the variable twice, only once, in either place. And right now trying to figure out why do I get a different outcome."

Comment: OK. In what point do you inspect `temp`? Just after the initialization in both cases?

Comment: declare variables together at first of function if you are using C.Then check whether if you have override the content of variable n.

Comment: @llmo Euro I have two breakpoints, each at lines after initialization. the two breakpoints are executed in both scenarios. I display temp value like so "display temp" right after each breakpoint

Comment: And your code is compiled with `-g` and no optimizations?

Comment: @MYMNeo as far I am aware, I am not touching either n, argv[0], or argv[0][1] for that matter, nor temp through the function

Comment: maybe your compiler sees, that temp is never used, and does not initialize it at al (why should he)

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't know, I am new to C, and new to gdb. How can I figure out if it is optimized?

Comment: it is not Optimized if you have compiler Option -O0 (or used the appropriate Menue if you are a mouse-user)

Comment: I have lame question. You expect your program to take *three* parameters, right? as in "progname copy srcfile dstfile". Is that correct?

Comment: the program would be run as ./programfile 4 readfile.bmp writefile.bmp IF running from gdb I set the arguments like "set args 4 readfile.bmp writefile.bmp" and then run with gdb

Comment: Here is an easy but stupid way to help you find problem.Adding printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", argv[1], temp, n);` following each statement such as `fread`, `fwrite`.Then check out the printed message

Answer (score 0):

So you never read `temp` or `n` after initialization, if I understand your code.  It's possible in the second case that the compiler has figured that out (depending on the level of optimization) and removed it.

Comment: i thought so also in my deleted answer, but why behaves the programm right in scenario 1?!?

Comment: `n` was just set in case 1.  Perhaps there the optimization window is small enough to only "see" a few statements back and forward.

Comment: If optimization would be aggressive enough to use the whole `main` function as the optimization window, it could delete both `temp`s as well as `n` as write-only variables.

Comment: @Idav1s Could you clarify this part? I never read temp or n after initialization (you mean I never use the variables?) If so, from your answer, could I assume that in the SCENARIO 2 if I use the variables after I declare, the value of temp should = n and not 0? thank you

Comment: After you initialize `n` it's never used, except to initialize `temp` which is never subsequently used. I'm assuming some windowed optimization is happening here.  In both cases, the storage for `temp` or `n` isn't optimized away.  In the first case, you've just computed `n`, and the window can't see to the end of `main` yet.  But it's only an instruction or two to set `temp`. In the second case maybe the window can see the end of `main`, and so it doesn't set up `temp`, since it's not used.